# How can I extend property inside of nested CSS?

Tags: html, css, sass

I wanna know how can I use `@extend` in SASS when I have nested CSS.
Here's my code , I wanna extend all property in a button which is in `section` to my `.last-btn`

```
section {

  button {

    background - color: rgb(111, 190, 190);
    border: none;
    padding: 2e m;
    border - radius: 10e m; &
    : hover {
      background: rebeccapurple;
    } &
    ::after {
      content: "Hello";
    }
  }

}

.last - btn {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try with:

```
 .last - btn {
   @extend section>button;
 }
```

but I haven't tested it.
Or you can make a mixin.

Comment: "complex selector may not be extended" I got this error

Comment: try creating a mixin 
https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/mixin

Comment: yeah. I think this is the only way that I can do this

Comment: do you need help?

Comment: No. I think using mixin is only way. I was just looking for a way to do this without mixin

Comment: If it doesn't work as I wrote it then I think mixin is the only way... Otherwise you should use javascript, and make sure that when the button is inside the section, it is assigned a class and so then you can do the extension of that class. So it will be extended only to the button that is inside the section.

Comment: nothing. :) could you help me with a positive vote on my answer: P

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check the below code? Hope it will work for you.

```
section {
  button{

    background-color:rgb(111, 190, 190);
    border: none;
    padding: 2em;
    border-radius: 10em;
    &:hover{
      background: rebeccapurple;
    }
    &::after{
      content: "Hello";
    }
  }
  .last-btn{
    @extend button;
  }
}
```

Please refer to this link: https://jsfiddle.net/yudizsolutions/sqv391w8/3/

Comment: no. actually it was the first thing that i tried and didn't worked